# Screamers: Are they possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, mutants

I have a species of humanoid based mutants called **Screamers.**

> Screamers are supposed to be genetically engineered humans. They are modified to have the strength of a male silverback gorilla, and an average height of about 8 feet tall. They’re also supposed to be immune to aging, disease, and able to withstand higher amounts of radiation. Basically, they’re supposed to be my answer to Super Mutants from *Fallout*.

My question is, are these mutants feasibly possible? What, if anything, should I change?

Comment: "immune to aging and disease" may be the least believable...

Comment: @Matthew: Okay, maybe I could compromise and just make them really long-lived and hardened to disease?

Comment: I'm not sure what "feasibly possible" means. Does it mean *possible* (lots of things are "possible"), *feasible* (worthwhile; can be done conveniently), or *plausible* (believable in context)? I suspect you might actually mean "plausible", but it's not clear.

Comment: @user535733: Yeah, plausible

Comment: feasibly possible compared to what? What are the rules of the world we're working with? Tech level, population level, manufacture/production of the mutants, physiology (eating habits, caloric burn, healing abilities), what's their IQ? What does "immune to aging" mean (immortal?)? If this is a reality-check against present-day Earth, they're not feasible at all, so what's the reference?

Comment: @JBH: Yes, modern day earth. So please explain why they aren’t feasible and what I could fix!

Comment: We can't genetically control cancer, epilepsy, palsies, Parkinson's Disease today, much less create a laboratory Frankenstein. That means handwaving the creature's development using an "advanced R&D facility" concept like the DOOM and Resident Evil franchises. Once you allow that, you can rationalize anything you want, which makes the question moot. You might want to shift from [tag:reality-check] (which requires you to provide the reference for judgement) to asking "given the following baseline, does my creature pass suspension-of-disbelief quality?" (\*continued\*)

Comment: Please note that the creature you're inventing has been invented before and exists in pretty much every disease/research-gone-wild/zombie movie/game/story ever created. It's the "tank" creature compared to other stereotypes like the sniper, healer, recruiter, recon/scout, infantry/footman/grunt.... That's not a big deal as character/monster stereotypes are nearly impossible to avoid. It's how they're used (the story) that makes things different.

Comment: Since a child from the older cells of an adult basically resets the age, it is theoretically possible to renew tissue and reverse aging. But you would have to have some kind of very intelligently build migrating system of reproduced stemcells that move towards tissue that needs renewal and the nervous system will offer a differenr challenge altogether.

Answer (score 4):

**They were made for a purpose.**

If the point of these things is to roam the wasteland and attack on sight, I wonder why anyone would have made them.  They are not mutants.  They are genetically engineered to be the way they are.

I propose that these genetically engineered creatures are colonists, designed to withstand the rigors of harsh new worlds.  They would be sent as an advance to do the work of taming recently discovered worlds and producing environments suitable for later colonists of normal human stock.

The creators of these creatures were concerned that if they could reproduce, they would fill these new worlds with their own kind.  So they are created immortal, but sterile.

Now in the future, the ones on earth are ones that were left behind, never deployed to their new worlds.  They seek the company of their own kind.  And because of genetic imperative, they work, hard.  They were created to tame harsh lands.  Now earth has become that.  In their enclave these supers do what they were born to do, wrestling the sickened earth back to health.

---

And to them, it is not screaming.  It is singing.

Comment: You’ve got to be loud if you’re expecting anything you sing to be heard over the howling winds of the colony worlds.

Comment: @JoeBloggs - Gorilla people communicating via opera in the alien storm.  Yes, yes; the story writes itself.

Comment: IT WAS EARTH ALL ALOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG!!!!!

Comment: @Willk: They’re called Screamers cause of their really deep voice.

Comment: @DTCooper - can they carry a tune?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very hard.

Strength of a gorilla obviously possible, since gorillas have it. Eight feet tall perhaps possible, but this would be hard for upright position - can they also have posture akin to that of gorillas?

Immune to aging is probably very easy as soon as we figure out how aging works. They have to die eventually, but it's possible that they are very long-lived and with very sudden onset of disability and death (they live to the full then drop dead).

Immune to disease is not hard to engineer: we could modify their biochemistry to be incompatible with most of earth biome (change how some amino acids are coded, change some organic molecules left to right) so that most bacteria and all viruses won't thrive. Of course, they are vulnerable to specifically crafted modified diseases, that's their Achilles' heel.

It's harder to make them immune to autosomal diseases. I guess some of these will still manifest. However, you can handwave that they're pretty rare and usually detected in early life & removed from population.

Resistance to radiation is probably not very hard either - many organisms do that, we even know how they do it. Please note that radiation is exponential phenomenon - we can make them perform indefinitely in "not great, not terrible" environment, but they definitely won't withstand naked reactor core.